# Regex pattern for excluding script tag

Tags: regex

I am doing validation in spring boot request body . Need to do validation for name field, it has all character except  and . Any clue ?
name field should allow all string value except if the string contains  and  or both ?

Comment: except <script> and </script> or both

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.